# Is it possible to export a file in parts with Screenflow?

Tags: macos, mac, screencasts

I have a very long screencast in Screenflow, it's 90 minutes long. Is it possible to export it in parts, cutting it at markers or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

1. Select your timeline and press **I** (Mark → Mark In Point).
2. Drag the start/end of the blue region to adjust where you wish to begin and end the first part for export, or position the playhead and press **I** and **O** to mark the In and Out points respectively.

   [image]
3. Press **⌘E** (File → Export Selected Range…)